# m4a to mp3 converter for Windows

Tags: conversion, mp3

I'm looking for an .m4a to .mp3 converter for Windows XP, preferably open source.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Converting from lossy to lossy formats will result in quality loss. However i would probably recommend [free:ac](http://www.freac.org/) if you *have* to do it. Its FOSS, and has been fairly reliable and simple to use for me.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the quality loss. It can be pretty severe too.

Answer (score 5):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for sure.

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.
>
> FFmpeg is free software licensed under
>   the LGPL or GPL depending on your
>   choice of configuration options. If
>   you use FFmpeg or its constituent
>   libraries, you must adhere to the
>   terms of the license in question. You
>   can find basic compliance information
>   and get licensing help on our license
>   and legal considerations page.

Run something like this (there is a massive variety of configuration options available, but this will get you started):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp3
```

Comment: FFmpeg Doesn't support MP3 files out of the box

Answer (score 2):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net) would work, open source.

Besides being arguably the best player out there, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can [convert video/auto](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode). Also open source.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use iTunes (not OSS, I realize, but free as in beer), you can use the directions on [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1550).  Go to the `Edit` menu, click the `Import Settings` button and select the `MP3 Encoder`.  Now you can right click and save to MP3.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/download.html), it converts almost all types into another even mobile devices etc...And a short [video](http://format-factory.en.softonic.com/video/format-factory-how-to-convert-files-with-format-factory-207) about its capabilities...